# change orientation doesn't wok in com.android.support:design:23.2.0

Tags: android, orientation, android-recyclerview

In myfragment.java

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    StaggeredGridLayoutManager staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    if (isScreenChange()) {
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager);
    } else {
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    }
}

public boolean isScreenChange() {
    Configuration mConfiguration = getResources().getConfiguration(); 
    Log.i("SCREEN",mConfiguration.toString());
    int ori = mConfiguration.orientation; 
    if (ori == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        return true;
    } else if (ori == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {

        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It dose work in compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1',
but in com.android.support:design:23.2.0,whatever you rotate the screen,
it always show ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT

Comment: call `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'`

Answer (score 0):

Support Library 23.2.0 comes with below changes in RecyclerView as mentioned [HERE](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html)

> This release brings an exciting new feature to the LayoutManager API:
>   auto-measurement! This allows a RecyclerView to size itself based on
>   the size of its contents. This means that previously unavailable
>   scenarios, such as using WRAP_CONTENT for a dimension of the
>   RecyclerView, are now possible. You’ll find all built in
>   LayoutManagers now support auto-measurement.
>
> Due to this change, make sure to double check the layout parameters of
>   your item views: previously ignored layout parameters (such as
>   MATCH_PARENT in the scroll direction) will now be fully respected.
>
> If you have a custom LayoutManager that does not extend one of the
>   built in LayoutManagers, this is an opt-in API - you’ll be required to
>   call setAutoMeasureEnabled(true) as well as make some minor changes as
>   detailed in the Javadoc of the method.
>
> Note that although RecyclerView animates its children, it does not
>   animate its own bounds changes. If you would like to animate the
>   RecyclerView bounds as they change, you can use the Transition APIs.

Comment: This is not about the new feature "auto measurement". OP's concern is Fragment's `onConfigurationChanged()` method is not called during the screen orientation changes. For me, custom view's `onConfigurationChanged()` is not called but fragment `onConfigurationChanged()` method works fine.

Comment: @SankarV same here..the fragment can change it orientation,but the recyclerview can't . i want the recyclerview in the vertical use LinearLayoutManager, and in horizontal use StaggerGridLayoutManager

Comment: @meunicorn The issue occurs in the latest support library V23.2.0. Please use the previous version v23.1.1. I think we need a new version from Google with the fix for the bug.